# explicit instantiation of static var in class template

Tags: c++, static-members, explicit-instantiation

I have the following class with a static data member but linking failed with `undefined reference to X<int, int>::list`

```
#include <vector>

template < typename T1, typename T2 >
class X
{
    public:
    static std::vector< X*> list;
};

template<>
std::vector< X<int,int>* > X<int,int>::list;


int main()
{
    X<int,int>::list.push_back( new X<int,int> );

}
```

Comment: Adding `{}`, i.e `template<> std::vector< X<int,int>* > X<int,int>::list{};` fixes the issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tx7bj4aKz)

Comment: @Jarod42 And what is the reason why we need it?

Comment: you need to define it, not just declare.

Comment: I prefer to use `static inline std::vector<X*> list{};` so I don't have define it elsewhere.  Assuming a recent enough C++ standard.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai And why I need "sometimes" `{}` and sometimes not. Extended the example: https://godbolt.org/z/1aTMc9cxb  Sorry, I am a bit confused

Comment: `template <typename T> int Foo<T>::n; ` is a definition of the variable for the template.  `template<>
std::vector< X<int,int>* > X<int,int>::list;` is a declaration of a specialization of variable.

Comment: Because you "sometimes" define the primary, and "sometimes" declare a specialization.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  ... ubs... got it :-) Thanks!